# count(distinct(col_name)) not working in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am newbie in mysql, for learning i am using sample database of w3schools. in that i want to create a view **which will for each supplier, list the supplier name, the count of distinct products by the supplier (PCount), the count of distinct product categories by the supplier (CCount).**

here is my table structures

```
Suppliers                             Products
--------------------            ----------------------------
SupplierID                             ProductID
SupplierName                           ProductName  
ContactNumber                          SupplierID
Address                                CategoryID
City                                   Unit  
PostalCode                             Price
Country
Phone
```

What i have try is

```
SELECT s.SupplierName, COUNT(DISTINCT(p.ProductID)) as PCount, COUNT(DISTINCT(p.CategoryID)) as CCount FROM Suppliers as s 
right join Products as p 
on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
```

this is only giving me single SupplierName not all the supplier details with distinct product and distinct category.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY s.SupplierName`

Comment: The duplicate uses a different aggregate function (`GROUP_CONCAT` versus `COUNT`) but the principle is the same

Comment: @Nick i did not get your last comment.! you mean to say i can use any one of them.?

Comment: No, what I meant was that the reason the query in the duplicate didn't give the expected result was due to the lack of the `GROUP BY` clause, and that is the same reason that your query doesn't give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT s.SupplierName,
    COUNT(p1.ProductID) AS PCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p2.CategoryID) AS CCount
FROM Suppliers s
    LEFT JOIN Products p1 ON s.SupplierID=p1.SupplierID
    LEFT JOIN Products p2 ON s.SupplierID=p2.SupplierID
GROUP BY s.SupplierName
ORDER BY s.SupplierName
```